# PHP URL redirection header() function

Tags: php

```
header ("Location :   .")
```

this one stay at current web page or current directory?

```
header("Location :  ..")
```

this one goes to default home page?

Comment: Can you please describe your problem?

Comment: I not sure what it means  . versus ..  in header function.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, neither are correct.  You are required to use a full URL in any `Location` response headers.

Most browsers will allow for relative paths, but you're bound to find something that doesn't support this behavior.  For relative paths, `..` means the directory above the current one.  `.` means the current directory.